# C++ Array Help swapping values and printing

Tags: c++, arrays

You have an array of 5 integers: 5,4,3,2,1. Prompt the user for 2 values. The two integers will represent indexes within the array. You must swap the values in the two indexes, and then print out the array. Each value of the array should be printed on its own line.

If the numbers given to you are out of bounds, do not swap any elements, and print the array.

Not understanding where they want me to put the users input? Two indexes? Does that mean the first two values of the array?

Here's what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int my_array[] = {5,4,3,2,1};

int input;
cin >> input;

my_array[0] = input;

int second;
cin >> second;

my_array[1] = second;

//cout ... ?

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown no effort to solve the problem.

Comment: For swapping two elements, `std::swap` might be a good function to use.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework; if you have tried something and it is not working, please post the code and show us what you got

Comment: Sorry about that, new to stackoverflow. Posted what I have.

Comment: Here "Two indexes" means that you should you should swap the values of  `my_array[input]` and `my_array[second]`. But first check that `input` and `second` are valid inputs, and not 112 or something.

Answer (score 0):

whatever I understood from ur question is that u have to take two values  from user input if input values are in bound of array's possible indexes then **swap them** and print the array else print the given array as it is if anyone of them is not in array's possible indexes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int my_array[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};

int input1,input2,temp;
cin >> input1>>input2;
if(input1<5&&input2<5)
{
my_array[input1]=temp; //swap values of indexes of input
my_array[input2]=my_array[input1];
temp=my_array[input2];
}
for(i=0;i>5;i++){
cout<<my_array[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor adaptation from the below code that is verified working:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int my_array[] = { 5,4,3,2,1 };
    //
    int input1, input2, temp;
    cin >> input1 >> input2;
    if( input1 < 5 && input2 < 5 )
    {
        double temp = my_array[ input1 ];
        my_array[ input1 ] = my_array[ input2 ];
        my_array[ input2 ] = temp;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        cout << my_array[ i ] << endl;
    }
    //
    return 0;
}
```